# Scala UDFs as external Jars

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, scala-reflect

I have a object where I have written my Udf

```
package com.udf.sample
object UDFDetails {
  def udfIndexOf = (inputValue: String, matchCriteria: String) => {
  inputValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(matchCriteria)
}
```

}

If I register it directly then I get the return type as

```
org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,IntegerType,Some(List(StringType, StringType)))
```

Now this is in a different module, I want this udf to be used in my Spark processing.

So, I have am using reflection to use this udf and trying to register it using this

```
def registerUdfFunc() = {
     val udfDf = getDataFrame("UDF_TABLE")
     udfDf.collect.foreach { x =>
     registerDynamicUDF(x.getString(x.fieldIndex("className")), x.getString(x.fieldIndex("functionName")), x.getString(x.fieldIndex("udfName")));
}


private def registerDynamicUDF(objectName: String, udfFunction: String, udfName: String) = 
{
 val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
 val moduleSymbol = runtimeMirror.moduleSymbol(Class.forName(objectName))  
 var targetMethod = moduleSymbol.typeSignature.members.filter(x => 
 x.isMethod && x.name.toString == udfFunction).head.asMethod
 var function = runtimeMirror.reflect(runtimeMirror.reflectModule(moduleSymbol).instance).reflectMethod(targetMethod)()
 SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().udf.register(udfName, function)
 }
```

I have stored the Object name, UdfName(for registration), fucntionName in a table, from which I create dataframe and iterate through. 
Now when I Use

```
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().udf.register(udfName, function)
```

it gives me error, saying cannot register udf with type any

```
 (name: String,udf:org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction)org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction cannot be applied to (String, Any) spark.udf.register("index",function)
```

and if I try to cast it to UserDefinedFunction it gives me classcast exception.
What should I do, any Ideas?

Comment: what have you tried so far? please share the codes you've tried and specify the difficulty you are facing? If possible specify input and expected output too.

Comment: Assuming you add the JARs to the spark job, you should be able to register functions from these JARs as UDFs in your job. Add more details to your question, it's not clear where are you being stuck

Comment: When I try to use udf.register(String,func), the function i get from reflection has type any. Stuck there :(

Comment: @AlexSavitsky I have added the details, please see if you can help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried to use `.asInstanceOf[YourDesiredFunctionType]` on the reflection result? It's not pretty, but my guess is that the type information is lost when using reflection the way you do

Comment: Yeah, tried that, it gives classCast exception

Comment: Did you solve this issue eventually?

Comment: No, but found a workaround. I am registering the UDF's in the external jar only

Comment: for example
`def udfIndexOf() { 
    SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate().
     udf.register("index_of", (inputValue: String, matchCriteria: String) => { 
     inputValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(matchCriteria)  
    })  
  }`

Comment: Does this mean you needed to add spark dependencies to this external library build code. I want to do the same with my udfs but don't want to add spark dependencies to it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! So, I have created two jars, one jar with main application code, and external jar which is specifically registers these UDF's. 
And I have added this external jar to classpath.